# I am not able to get any of my JSLink working. What am I doing wrong

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013, jslink

We have SharePoint 2013 on Prem and I am trying to do some customizations using JS Link.  Even the most simple exercises are not working.  I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

New page - List added and jS Link = ~site/SiteAssets/js-test/OverRideCustomHeader.js

```
(function () {
var overrideContext = {};
overrideContext.Templates = {};
overrideContext.Templates.Header = overrideCustomHeader;
overrideContext.Templates.Footer = overrideCustomFooter;
SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideContext);
})();

function overrideCustomHeader() {
return “<h3>Our Custom Header</h3>”;
}

function overrideCustomFooter() {
return “<h3>Our Custom Footer</h3>”;
}
```

I expect to see a header and a footer display and they are not.

Answer (score 0):

Insert script editor webpart into the page and insert the script into script editor webpart(use correct 【"】).

```
(function () {
var overrideContext = {};
overrideContext.Templates = {};
overrideContext.Templates.Header = overrideCustomHeader;
overrideContext.Templates.Footer = overrideCustomFooter;
SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideContext);
})();

function overrideCustomHeader() {
return "<h3>Our Custom Header</h3>";
}

function overrideCustomFooter() {
return "<h3>Our Custom Footer</h3>";
}
```

[image]

[image]

Update:

Have you enabled Minimal Download Strategy?

[image]

[image]

JSLink won't work if url like `/_layouts/15/start.aspx#` , you could disable the feature.

Comment: Not following.  Putting this code directly into a script editor will not work.  In addition, not certain what your mean by using the correct ["].  I'm beginning to think that the code I have hear does not work for 2013 on-prem, but not certain.  Lastly, I'd like to figure out how to use js-link.  I can add javascript to a page directly or by reference, but how do use the power of js-link.  Thank you.

Comment: @SteveHarvancik - I realize this is an old thread, however what they mean is, you're using smart quotes, which are not translated correctly. You need the actual quotes (") in order for it to work. When you put something into a program like MS Word, it translates everything to smart quotes to make it look better. Using a text editor (like Notepad or even Notepad++) won't convert them.